# To show message to user that download is completed in another activity

Tags: android

I have six activities, in one of which i have to download a pdf. User can go in any of the activity after starting download, I want to show alert when the download is completed, if he is another activity then also.

Comment: An alert consisting of what? `Toast`, `AlertDialog`, `Notification`?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use Notification to achieve your requirement. For the basic start up please refer this link.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Hope this will help...

Comment: Nice tutorial for Showing Notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AsyncTask` to download the pdf, it'll continue to run even if your activity is in background. When the Download completes the `onPostExecute()` will get called where you can write codes to show alert.
Now one way to show alert in other activities is to start a `service`, if you want to show the alert in other activities too, which are not yours. Showing `Notification`, is another option.
But if you want to limit the alert to the activites inside your app, then you can have a boolean static variable in any of the class which can be set to true when the download finishes, and have a check in all of your activities for the value of the variable to show alerts.
Choose whatever option suits you.

Comment: I think a Service is the way to go. You can use a Toast or status bar notification when the download is complete. Unlike with an AsyncTask, you don't have to worry about whether the activity that started the download was restarted due to, say, a configuration change or the system killing it to reclaim resources.